# Map not loading in android app.Error:Failed to load map.could not contact google servers.This is probably an authentication issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have gone through many of the already existing similar questions here,but couldn't find a solution to my problem. Have tried the correct procedure to get the API Key. Please help. Thanks in advance . Here's the code : 
**Java file** :

```
public class nearby extends FragmentActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        super.onCreate(saved);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rl, R.anim.lr);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.nearby);
    }
}
```

**XML file** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest File** :
    `

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
android:name="com.example.foodtrip.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.foodtrip.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission           android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name="com.example.foodtrip.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainMenu"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".AboutMe"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".cuisine"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name=".nearby"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"              android:value="AIzaSyAgZJ69P3RWQHCdr6id4RIgJ4pEL0i-cGU"/>
</application>

</manifest>`
```

`

Logcat Snap : 
  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWqhO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

According to you Manifest, I think you missed this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: Tried it . Still not loading the map .

Comment: You have to post logcat snap

Comment: Have edited my question with the logcat snap . Please look into it

Comment: if somebody still looking answer, check here - the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17947755/1891118